# Apply jQuery formula to individual div values that contain certain words in class

Tags: jquery, each

I have the following block of html:

```
<div class="product BLACKSHIRT">
<span class="displayPrice">£50</span>
</div>
<div class="product WHITESHIRT">
<span class="displayPrice">£40</span>
</div>
<div class="product GREENSHIRT">
<span class="displayPrice">£55</span>
</div>
<div class="product YELLOWSHIRT">
<span class="displayPrice">£50</span>
</div>
<div class="product BLACKJACKET">
<span class="displayPrice">£60</span>
</div>
<div class="product WHITESHORTS">
<span class="displayPrice">£20</span>
</div>
<div class="product BLACKTROUSERS">
<span class="displayPrice">£30</span>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is pick out each div has either "SHIRT" or "JACKET" as part of the class name, and then hooks out the value of the inner span - and adds 15 to the current value, so for example

```
<div class="product BLACKSHIRT">
<span class="displayPrice">£50</span>
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="product BLACKSHIRT">
<span class="displayPrice">£65</span>
</div>
```

Is this possible? I don't have any control over the existing html and am aware that the "£" needs to be stripped in order to make the value into a number.

Comment: Anyway, you can use `$("[class*=SHIRT]")` to look for this substring.

Comment: @Barmar What about the class `WHITESHIRT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) `*=`.

```js
$("[class*=SHIRT] .displayPrice, [class*=JACKET] .displayPrice").html((i, oldhtml) => '£' + (15 + parseFloat(oldhtml.substr(1))).toFixed(2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product BLACKSHIRT">
  <span class="displayPrice">£50</span>
</div>
<div class="product WHITESHIRT">
  <span class="displayPrice">£40</span>
</div>
<div class="product GREENSHIRT">
  <span class="displayPrice">£55</span>
</div>
<div class="product YELLOWSHIRT">
  <span class="displayPrice">£50</span>
</div>
<div class="product BLACKJACKET">
  <span class="displayPrice">£60</span>
</div>
<div class="product WHITESHORTS">
  <span class="displayPrice">£20</span>
</div>
<div class="product BLACKTROUSERS">
  <span class="displayPrice">£30</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect. One additional question.. How could I get this to output the result if the original element has decimal places (eg <span class="displayPrice">£54.95</span>)? At the moment it would output £69 rather than £69.95. I tried adding in .toFixed(2) with no luck.

Comment: Use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`

Comment: Thanks again. I got that far, but if the total should be 54.50 or 54.00, the result is 54.5 or 54. Is there a way to show the zero's if they should be there?

Comment: `toFixed(2)` should work. I've updated the answer to show how to do it.

Comment: Thanks yet again! I did try this but had fiddled around with the code before and really over complicated it. Many, many thanks!